# All my tasks have RACK_LOCAL locality level

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I have 4 node hadoop cluster and I run spark jobs in it. Jobs are very basic, like word count for example. A have the following problems with my spark setup:

1. All my tasks are RACK_LOCAL level, even simple map tasks

....
    16/05/19 15:36:14 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 24.0 in stage 1.1 (TID 451, 217.69.134.5, partition 65,RACK_LOCAL, 2168 bytes)
    16/05/19 15:36:14 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 21.0 in stage 1.1 (TID 448) in 6635 ms on 217.69.134.5 (14/76)
    16/05/19 15:36:14 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 25.0 in stage 1.1 (TID 452, 217.69.134.5, partition 67,RACK_LOCAL, 2168 bytes)
    16/05/19 15:36:14 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 22.0 in stage 1.1 (TID 449) in 6858 ms on 217.69.134.5 (15/76)
    16/05/19 15:36:20 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 26.0 in stage 1.1 (TID 453, 217.69.134.5, partition 68,RACK_LOCAL, 2168 bytes)
    16/05/19 15:36:20 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 24.0 in stage 1.1 (TID 451) in 6872 ms on 217.69.134.5 (16/76)
    16/05/19 15:36:21 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 27.0 in stage 1.1 (TID 454, 217.69.134.5, partition 75,RACK_LOCAL, 2168 bytes)
    16/05/19 15:36:21 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 23.0 in stage 1.1 (TID 450) in 7049 ms on 217.69.134.5 (17/76)
    16/05/19 15:36:21 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 28.0 in stage 1.1 (TID 455, 217.69.134.5, partition 76,RACK_LOCAL, 2168 bytes)
    16/05/19 15:36:21 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 25.0 in stage 1.1 (TID 452) in 6893 ms on 217.69.134.5 (18/76)
    16/05/19 15:36:23 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 29.0 in stage 1.1 (TID 456, 217.69.134.5, partition 84,RACK_LOCAL, 2168 bytes)
    16/05/19 15:36:23 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 1.1 (TID 428) in 43633 ms on 217.69.134.5 (19/76)
    16/05/19 15:36:25 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 30.0 in stage 1.1 (TID 457, 217.69.134.8, partition 85,RACK_LOCAL, 2168 bytes)
    16/05/19 15:36:25 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 6.0 in stage 1.1 (TID 433) in 43612 ms on 217.69.134.8 (20/76)
    16/05/19 15:36:25 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 31.0 in stage 1.1 (TID 458, 217.69.134.8, partition 90,RACK_LOCAL, 2168 bytes)
    16/05/19 15:36:25 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 4.0 in stage 1.1 (TID 431) in 44555 ms on 217.69.134.8 (21/76)
.....

2. I cannot do tasks that require shuffle, like join, distinct, etc., they hang and go down.

   16/05/19 15:38:33 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 8.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 419, 217.69.134.8): FetchFailed(BlockManagerId(7, 217.69.134.6, 33955), s
   huffleId=0, mapId=6, reduceId=8, message=
   org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Failed to connect to /217.69.134.6:33955
           at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:323)
           at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:300)
           at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:51)
           at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
           at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
           at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
           at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
           at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
           at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
           at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
           at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
           at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:452)
           at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:280)
           at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1766)
           at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:239)
   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /217.69.134.6:33955

What could be wrong with my configs?